# Annotated Hibernate Spring not returning objects correctly - template free, spring free dao

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

I've spent about 8 hours researching and I cannot find a solution so I'm creating my first post here!

I'm getting the following error when hitting the getVote function as the object doesn't return anything.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.client.dao.impl.VoteDaoImpl.getVote(VoteDaoImpl.java:51)
at com.client.dao.impl.VoteDaoImpl.incrementVote(VoteDaoImpl.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy125.incrementVote(Unknown Source)
at com.client.action.VoteActionImpl.execute(VoteActionImpl.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Doing this:
Query query=currentSession().createQuery("from com.gasx.model.Vote where id=?");
Returns an object but it doesn't appear to function correctly (my logging stops).
Config looks like this. First time using annotations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   ">

   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcldb" />
            <property name="username" value="client" />
            <property name="password" value="client" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="sessionFactory"
                 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <!--property name="packagesToScan" value="com.client.model" /-->
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>    
                    <!--prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop-->
                    <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</prop>                
                </props>
            </property>
            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                    <value>com.client.model.Vote</value>                        
                </list>
            </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="voteDao" class="com.client.dao.impl.VoteDaoImpl" />

    <bean id="voteAction" class="com.client.action.VoteActionImpl">
        <property name="voteDao" ref="voteDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>     
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   
    <context:annotation-config />   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.client.dao.impl" />
</beans>
```

DAO Implementation

```
package com.client.dao.impl;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.client.dao.VoteDao;
import com.client.model.Vote;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class VoteDaoImpl implements VoteDao{
private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(VoteDaoImpl.class);
//private Vote voteBean;
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/**
 * @return the sessionFactory
 */

private Session currentSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

@Autowired
public VoteDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
}

public Vote getVote(int id){
    logger.info("getVote");
    //Query query=currentSession().createQuery("from com.client.model.Vote where id=?");
    //setParameter(0, id).list().get(0);

    Session session = currentSession();
    Vote vote=(Vote)session.get(Vote.class, id);


/*      if (vote==null){
        logger.info("Object was null");
    }else{
        logger.info("Object isn't null!");
    }
    */
    logger.info("Vote total: " + String.valueOf(vote.getVoteTotal()));
    return vote;
}

public void updateVote(Vote vote){
    currentSession().update(vote);      
    currentSession().flush();
}

/*
 * 
 * incements the vote.id=id 
 * 
 */
public void incrementVote(int id){
    logger.info(" increment vote");
    Vote vote=getVote(id);
    vote.setVoteTotal(vote.getVoteTotal()+1);
    updateVote(vote);

}
}
```

Model

```
package com.client.model;
import com.client.dao.*;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
//import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="vote")
public class Vote {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="vote_total")
private int voteTotal;

/**
 * @return the id
 */

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the voteTotal
 */

public int getVoteTotal() {
    return voteTotal;
}

/**
 * @param vote1Total
 *            the vote1Total to set
 */
public void setVoteTotal(int voteTotal) {
    this.voteTotal = voteTotal;
}
}
```

There is an interface for the dao

```
package com.client.dao;

import org.hibernate.classic.Session;

import com.client.model.Vote;


public interface VoteDao {
public Vote getVote(int id);
public void updateVote(Vote vote);
public void incrementVote(int id);
}
```

Any ideas? I'm stumped. If you need any info please let me know.

Comment: Welcome. Which line is the line 51 (`com.client.dao.impl.VoteDaoImpl.getVote(VoteDaoImpl.java:51)`) ?

Comment: I think it is easier to use HibernateTemplate instead of using SessionFactory in your DAO

Comment: Hibernate templates aren't necessary any more. I did try using hibernateTemplates though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project was okay... The issue was I forgot that in oracle you have to commit. I was inserting my seed data but the app couldn't see it as it was never committed. Cannot believe I did that... It has been a couple years since I worked with oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome,

The String XML config file overrides the Spring annotation config, so you have to edit your Spring XML file with the following :

```
<bean id="voteDao" class="com.client.dao.impl.VoteDaoImpl">
   <constructor-arg><ref bean="sessionFactory"/></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still no luck. I've tried hibernate templates, xml config. I get 0 objects back even when hibernate generates SQL that will actually run in the db.

Comment: Are you still getting the NullPointerException ?

Comment: I rewrote the entire application, tried everything possible, and finally I think the issue all this time, was that I did not run 'commit' after inserting my seed data...